# Customize ModelAdmin listing in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe, modeladmin

Is it possible to change or add custom `summary_fields` into a listing from a `ModelAdmin` extends? Actually I'm able to filter a custom field named Type but I don't know how to customize the `summary_fields`. This is my actual code:

```
class Profiles3ModelAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    public static $menu_icon = 'mysite/images/peoples.png';
    public static $managed_models = array('Member'); 
    public static $url_segment = 'membres'; 
    public static $menu_title = 'Membres';

    public function getList() {

        $group = Group::get()->filter('Code', array('Membres'))->first();
        $list = $group->Members()->filter('Type', 1 );

        return $list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query should be able to use `$list = Member::get()->filter(array('Groups.Code' => 'Membres', 'Type' => 1));` if I recall correctly. Just gets it down to one line.

Usually to add to the summary you would add it to your class's model. So in this case on `Member` you would apply a `DataExtension` that had:

```
<?php
    class MyMemberDataExtension extends DataExtension{
        private static $summary_fields = array(
            'Type'
        );
    }
```